# How to print return values inside method of a class in python

Tags: python

I was working on an online tutorial on class in python, then I tried to print out the value in the return and getting error.

```
class A:
    def fun(self):
        return 5
    print(fun())

obj=A()
obj.fun()
```

I know that `print(obj.fun())` will print the value but i want that to be printed inside function when it calls.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonTraining\Day8\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class A:
  File "D:\PythonTraining\Day8\test.py", line 4, in A
    print(fun())
TypeError: A.fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Just remove `self` from the function call

Comment: `print` before `return`?

Comment: "but i want that to be printed inside function when it calls." If you want the `print` to happen when you call the function, should the `print` be inside the function, or outside of it? Currently, is it inside the function, or outside? How do you know? Next: if the function returns `5`, and you also want it to print `5`, what should you pass to `print`? If you are already inside the function, should you call it again in order to get that value? Or do you already have it?

Comment: "I know that print(obj.fun()) will print the value but i want that to be printed inside function when it calls."  So put `print(5)` inside the function.  How else do you think it will print when called?

Comment: the reason i asked for printing is i want to store the value for further usage. if i can print means same value can be stored as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, just make `fun` into a static (non-instance) method:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def fun():
        return 5
    print(fun())


obj = A()
obj.fun()
```

**Edit:** still not sure why, but the above code only works in Python 3.10 or higher. It looks like the fix in 3.7+ would be to move the `print` statement outside the class instead:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def fun():
        return 5
print(A.fun())
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this code with python 3.7, but it works fine with 3.10

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess I *was* testing in 3.10. Huh, that's pretty weird.

Comment: I updated with notes on the behavior between py versions. I agree that's kind of strange though.

Answer (score 1):

The `print(fun())` inside the class doesn't have any useful meaning; `fun` is an instance method that takes a `self` argument, and in the context of the class definition there is no `self`.  That aside, any code in the class definition is executed when the class is defined (only once), and you want this to happen every time the function is called.

What you want to do is put the `print` statement *inside* `fun` so it will happen whenever `fun` is called on any given instance.

```
class A:
    def fun(self):
        print(5)
        return 5

obj=A()
obj.fun()  # prints "5"
```

If you want a solution that you can apply to any function without having to modify the body of the function itself, use a decorator:

```
def print_return(f):
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(r)
        return r
    return wrapped_f

class A:
    @print_return
    def fun(self):
        return 5

obj=A()
obj.fun()  # prints "5"
```

Note that most of the time, you don't want to do either of the above things -- if a function returns a value, it should usually be up to the caller to decide whether to print it or do something else with it, not the function itself (this is an example of the "single responsibility principle" -- functions are easier to work with when they're responsible for a single thing, i.e. either returning a value or printing it but not both at once).

In this case, the caller is the line of code that calls `obj.fun()`, so if you want to `print` the value, you'd do it there:

```
class A:
    def fun(self):
        return 5

obj=A()
print(obj.fun())  # prints "5"
```

Comment: `print(fun())` has meaning, just not the one the OP might expect. `fun` is a regular function, but one that implements the descriptor protocol and returns a *different* callable object when accessed via an instance of the class.

Comment: (And no, we don't want to make the OP learn about the descriptor protocol now, just to be aware of the difference between trying to call `fun` directly vs as an instance method.)